# Handle only controller requests with middleware

Tags: http, asp.net-core, middleware

I have simple asp core middleware

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Web.Identity
{
    public class UserContextHttpMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public UserContextHttpMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(context.Request.Path);

            return _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

After refresh page i have this in output

```
/
/assets/images/avatar-2.jpg
/assets/images/avatar-3.jpg
/assets/images/avatar-6.jpg
/assets/images/avatar-5.jpg
/assets/images/avatar-7.jpg
/assets/images/avatar-8.jpg
/assets/images/avatar-4.jpg
/assets/images/avatar-1.jpg
/images/user-background.png
/assets/images/avatar-10.jpg
/assets/images/avatar-9.jpg
```

First line is request to controler. Other lines is requests to static content.
So, how can i filter only request that will be handled by controller and ignore request to static content? How can know is current request is request to controller?

Comment: Register it after your static files middleware. They are executed in the order they are registered, see the graphics https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware ;)

Answer (score 3):

Middlewares are executed in the order they are registered (the `app.UseXxx` calls, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware)).

So if you register your middleware just before the MVC middleware, it should only log these. Be aware that it will also log non-existing routes though.

```
app.UseMiddleware<UserContextHttpMiddleware>();
app.UseMvc();
```

Alternatively you can register your middleware to actions, which is a bit more complicated (see [Using middleware in the filter pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#using-middleware-in-the-filter-pipeline) docs).

```
public class UserContextHttpPipeline
{
    public Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) 
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<UserContextHttpMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Then register it as a global filter

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new MiddlewareFilter(typeof(UserContextHttpMiddleware2)));
});
```

This will register the middleware to each action and will be called after Mvc middleware. This should also make sure only valid actions will be logged and invalid routes are not.